# sum of number of rows returned by count T-sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Have database hold information on persons login into and out of the system

I run the following to find the number of times a person has login in over a period of time.

```
SELECT Count(Distinct(Date)) as Counter, 
       COUNT(*) as CNT
FROM InOutUserStatus
where date > '2019-03-11' and 
      Date < '2019-03-21' and 
      Email = 'xxxxxx.xxxxx@xxxxxxxxxx.com' group by Date
```

this returns

```
    Counter CNT
  1    1     2
  2    1     1
  3    1     1
```

The results may vary but I need to be able to get a sum of the number of rows returned which in this case would be 3 which would be the number of days that persons login in to the system.
A person may login many times during a day.
I cannot see a away of acquiring the number of rows from the query?

Comment: You mean that you want the count of rows returned?

Comment: Consider **[`@@ROWCOUNT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rowcount-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)**

Comment: To go on a slight tangent here, I'd argue it'd be a better idea to count the number of rows _in code_, if you're able to do that, because with the answers provided below you'd seemingly have to go back to the database and run an almost duplicated query, or you'd have to include the number of rows as a new column which would repeat the value many times.  Would it be easy enough to just do `yourQueryResult.Rows.Count` (C#)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GROUP BY` is not needed for that case only aggregation is enough :

```
SELECT Count(Distinct [Date]) as Counter
FROM InOutUserStatus
WHERE date > '2019-03-11' AND 
      date < '2019-03-21' AND 
      Email = 'xxxxxx.xxxxx@xxxxxxxxxx.com';
```

Comment: Spot on, Can not believe I missed that thank you

Comment: @Roger Then please mark this suggestion as the answer. Because that is how SO is designed to work - questions get **answered** so that others with similar questions can find **answers**

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps wrap the whole query in a subquery and apply a count

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM   (

         SELECT Count(Distinct(Date)) as Counter, COUNT(*) as CNT
         FROM   InOutUserStatus
         WHERE  date > '2019-03-11' and
                Date < '2019-03-21' and
                Email = 'xxxxxx.xxxxx@xxxxxxxxxx.com'
         GROUP BY Date
       ) a
```

Comment: Why `GROUP BY Date` is needed here?